# How to initialize atom in thread safe manner?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, clojure

Let's say I have an atom:

```
(def my-atom (atom nil))
```

Then I initialize it as follows:

```
(defn init-atom [init-value]
  (when (nil? @my-atom)
    (reset! my-atom init-value)))
```

If `init-atom` is called concurrently from different threads, I race condition may occur. I'm looking for a way to safely and correctly initialize an atom. Anything there?

UPD:

Actually I'm initializing it as follows:

```
(defn init-atom [produce-init-fn]
  (when (nil? @my-atom)
    (reset! my-atom (produce-init-fn)])))
```

`produce-init-fn` may contain side effects.

Comment: Why would you need to call `init-atom` concurrently from different threads? And more importantly, why would you use [global state](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/148108) anyway?

Comment: In my domain this atom is cache accessible from different threads. So one at first checks whether there's anything. if nothing - puts value there. @SamEstep

Comment: Once the atom is initialized, will its value ever change after that? In other words, by "cache", do you mean like the atom used in [`memoize`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memoize), or like a [`promise`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/promise) that only receives a value once?

Comment: It's like memoize, e.g. there may be multiple writes to the atom @SamEstep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will make sure that the atom is initialized only once:

```
(defn init-atom [init-value]
  (swap! my-atom #(when (nil? %) init-value)))
```

Atom and `swap!` semantics guarantee that the function passed to `swap!` will be executed atomically.

If you pass a function producing the init value then it won't work as swap! might invoke the function multiple times in case of conflicting transactions. Then you need to use some kind of locking like in the other answer:

```
(let [o (Object.)]
  (defn init-atom [init-value-fn]
    (locking o
      (swap! my-atom #(when (nil? %) (init-value-fn))))))
```

`init-value-fn` still might be called more than once if there are other concurrent transactions with `my-atom`.

If you need to support lazy initialization and the `init-value-fn` is known upfront and the same for all the threads you can just wrap it into `delay` and then it will be called only once and its result will be cached and reused:

```
(def my-init-value (delay init-value-fn))

(defn init-atom []
  (swap! my-atom #(when (nil? %) @my-init-value)))
```

Comment: Actually, I'm calling a function to produce init value. Sorry, for incorrect initial question.

Comment: I have updated my answer to cover your changes in the question.

Comment: Your last version is just using `delay` to reimplement `delay`. Might as well just `(def my-atom (delay init-value-fn))` and never call `init-atom` at all.

Comment: That's true if you assume that there will be no other code changing the atom value later.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
(let [o (Object.)]
  (defn init-atom [init-value]
    (locking o
      (when (nil? @my-atom)
        (reset! my-atom init-value)))))
```